# large fileupload using blockBlobClient.uploadData to azure blob failing in angular

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage

I am using the @azure/storage-blob library in an Angular application to upload files to Azure blob storage. I was able to successfully upload a 6 GB folder to the blob in 21 minutes. However, when I attempted to upload a 13.5 GB folder, my application froze after 15 minutes and threw the following REST error. I am not sure why it is not able to send the request to the blob.

I have already checked the SAS URL and made sure that the start time and end time are valid and have all the necessary permissions (read, add, create, write).

For debugging purposes, I have set up the following CORS settings:

- Allowed origins: *
- Allowed verbs: DELETE, GET, HEAD, MERGE, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
- Allowed headers: *
- Exposed headers: *
- Maximum age (seconds): 86400

Please refer to the following console error for more details:

ERROR Error: RestError: Failed to send request to https://xxxxxxxx /copy.txt?sv=2021-10-04&st=2023-06-16T21%3A25%3A49Z&se=2023-06-16T22%3A30%3A49Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=xxxxx

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
xxxxxxxx /copy1.txt?sv=2021-10-04&st=2023-06-16T21%3A25%3A49Z&se=2023-06-16T22%3A30%3A49Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=xxxxx

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
xxxxxxxx /copy2.txt?sv=2021-10-04&st=2023-06-16T21%3A25%3A49Z&se=2023-06-16T22%3A30%3A49Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=xxxxx

```
let uploadDataResponse: Observable<BlobUploadCommonResponse>;
const observablesBlob: any[] = [];
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(sasUrl);
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("");
from(this.selectedFiles).forEach(async file => {
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(file.webkitRelativePath);

  uploadDataResponse = from(blockBlobClient.uploadData(file.slice(0, file.size, file.type), {
    onProgress: (prg) => {
      this.archiveService.setProgressBarValues({fileName: file.name, bytes: prg.loadedBytes, uploadComplete: false});
    }
  }));
  observablesBlob.push(uploadDataResponse);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are getting the error `ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` while uploading the blob of size 13.5 GB . I understand that the same application works fine, for smaller blob sizes.

Looking at the error message it is clear that this isn't an Azure Storage error (not a server side error), but a client side error. The error seems like the browser is running out of shared memory. At times, while uploading large file sizes, resource exhaustion can be seen.

Could you check if you are seeing high memory being consumed by the browser ? Is it the same behavior observed on other browsers too ?
Did you try increasing the client side resource limits on the browser ?

***On a side note:*** You could also try splitting the entire blob in to smaller blocks (chunks) as shown below and check if that helps ?

```
      await blockBlobClient.uploadData(browserFile, {
      blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
      concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
      onProgress: ev => console.log(ev)
```

Refer the sample code snippet [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/f4e97da0dc5a146536391942e8ef1d5919bb3735/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/v12/javascript/advancedRequestOptions.js#L88).

Hope this helps. If you have any follow-up questions on this, please let me know. I would be happy to answer those.